# How to Prevent rounding numbers in DataGridView using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, rounding

I have a datagridview in a windows forms vb.net application. My goal is to have any number over 0.999999999999 12 significant digits to be rounded down to 0.99999999999 11 significant digits. I want to prevent vb.net from rounding these values up to 1. This is how I'm implementing this but I can't figure out which DataGridView Event handler to use.

```
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value <= 0.999999999999 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 0.99999999999
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it prior to loading it,

```
dataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F11"
```

or 
You can write custom logic in the [dataGridView_CellFormatting event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)